# Sense/NET: Instalação e configuração programática

Tags: .net, cms, sistema-de-arquivos

Estou trabalhando no momento em soluções que requerem o armazenamento de arquivos enviados pelos usuários, associação de metadata a estes arquivos e disponibilização destes para outros usuários e tarefas comuns de manutenção (clean-up, etc.)

Como não desejo reinventar a roda, procurei por soluções de CMS para .NET e encontrei o projeto [Sense/NET](http://www.sensenet.com/), que é uma solução completa para um portal de CMS. Entretanto, seu escopo é muito maior do que o aspecto que necessito (que acredito seria apenas o PortalFileSystem).

No meu mundo ideal, eu gostaria de ativar o PFS programaticamente (estipulando a string de conexão ao banco e quaisquer outras configurações necessárias) por dentro de uma library class isolada - porém não encontrei nenhuma documentação neste respeito.

## Pergunta

É possível inicializar e configurar programaticamente o módulo PortalFileSystem?

## Bônus

Existe alguma outra alternativa que não contemplei que atende melhor às minhas necessidades?

Comment: Nunca nem ouvi falar. Vou dar uma brincada até.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro o [Kooboo CMS](http://www.kooboo.com/docs/kooboo-cms/all). É um CMS ASP.NET de fácil configuração e tem uma interface bem intuitiva. Possui suporte à biblioteca de arquivos, Membership de usuários, dentre outros recursos que podem te ajudar. Fiz um [post com um getting started](http://godoy.net.br/asp-net/getting-started-kooboo-cms-net/) no meu blog.

Utilizando Roles de usuários você pode, por exemplo, dar permissão específica para gerenciar biblioteca de arquivos aos usuários no seu projeto.